# Cannot call 'operator /' with argument

Tags: pine-script

I can't formula entry rightly. I have following mistakes:

line 28: Cannot call 'operator /' with argument 'expr0'='totalRevenueBySampling'. An argument of 'fun_ref[totalRevenueBySampling]' type was used but a 'const int' is expected
Cannot call 'operator /' with argument 'expr1'='totalOperatingExpensesBySampling'. An argument of 'fun_ref[totalOperatingExpensesBySampling]' type was used but a 'const int' is expected;
line 28: Variable 'Rs' is not found in scope 'Rs', cannot register side effect

Here is a script looks:

**Kr = Ra / Rs**, where **Ra** = Sa / Ea, and where **Rs** = Ss / Es

Here is a script I wrote:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Competitiveness")

// Ra (effectiveness from operations)
// Sa - Total Revenue
// Ea - Total Operating Expenses
Ra() =>
    Sa = request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "TOTAL_REVENUE", "FQ")
    Ea = request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "TOTAL_OPER_EXPENSE", "FQ")
    Ra = Sa / Ea

// Rs (effectiveness from operations by sampling)
// Ss - Total Revenue by Sampling
// Es - Total Operating Expenses by Sampling
sym1 = input.symbol("", "Ticker")
sym2 = input.symbol("", "Ticker")

Ss() =>
    obj1 = request.financial(sym1, "TOTAL_REVENUE", "FQ")
    obj2 = request.financial(sym2, "TOTAL_REVENUE", "FQ")
    totalRevenueBySampling = math.avg(obj1, obj2)
    
Es() =>
    obj1 = request.financial(sym1, "TOTAL_OPER_EXPENSE", "FQ")
    obj2 = request.financial(sym2, "TOTAL_OPER_EXPENSE", "FQ")
    totalOperatingExpensesBySampling = math.avg(obj1, obj2)

Rs() =>
    Rs = Ss / Es

// Kr (effectiveness from operations ratio)
Kr() =>
    Kr = Ra / Rs

plot(Kr(), "Kr", color.aqua, 2)
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `()` to your function calls.

```
Rs() =>
    Rs = Ss() / Es()

// Kr (effectiveness from operations ratio)
Kr() =>
    Kr = Ra() / Rs()
```